# Fillbetween doesn't fill entire area under graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to  fill the area under a graph in tikz so that it looks like this:

[image: Goal]

However, this is what I end up with:

[image: Actual reults]

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      domain=0:10,
      samples=100,
      enlargelimits=false,
     ]
     \addplot [very thick, red!50!black, name path=f] {gauss(5,1)};
     \addplot [name path=axis] coordinates {(0,0)(10,0)};
     \addplot [thick,fill=green,fill opacity=0.4]
           fill between[of=f and axis,soft clip={domain=0:3.5}];
     \addplot [thick,fill=red,fill opacity=0.4]
           fill between[of=f and axis,soft clip={domain=3.5:6.5}];
     \addplot [thick,fill=green,fill opacity=0.4]
           fill between[of=f and axis,soft clip={domain=6.5:10}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

While fixing the MWE I noticed that if I remove `enlargelimits=false` the filling seems to work as intended, but I don't want to enlarge the limits.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you comment out the line `enlargelimits=false,` then the problem is gone. Just an observation, no explanation.

Comment: But why do you want to fix it? This white area makes the plot more fascinating anyway. ;-) You just have to come up with an interpretation of what it means.

Comment: Here is a workaround: replace `enlargelimits=false` by `enlargelimits=0.002`; the two versions are almost identical, but no white area in the second case.

Comment: It seems that with `enlargelimits=0` the top of the graph is cut off, so that the curve now consists of two parts. Therefore also the area below the split curve falls into two parts, which are not well defined. The algorithm implemented in tikz apparently 'decides' for this partitioning of the area.

Comment: @gernot Of course, that makes perfect sense! Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: This strange behavior is coming from a bug which is already reported in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/111/). [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350507/95441) I provided an answer showing where it is coming from.

Comment: For the record: With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 your example gives the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative solution even without using the `fillbetween` library. The fill plots are written first so they appear below the other plot. You could solve this with layers, but if changing the order is not a problem, then there you go.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    domain=0:10,
    samples=100,
    enlargelimits=false,
    ]
%
\addplot[fill=green, opacity=.4, domain=0:3.5] {gauss(5,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=red, opacity=.4, domain=3.5:6.5] {gauss(5,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot[fill=green, opacity=.4, domain=6.5:10] {gauss(5,1)} \closedcycle;

\addplot [very thick, red!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the order is of no importance. This works great and is a much neater solution than my original one. Thank you, I really appreciate it!